# SecureSocial - Show a different home page if the user is logged in

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, securesocial

I need to show different home pages depending on whether the user is logged in or not, just like Twitter or Instagram does:

- If the user has not authenticated, the default cover home page must be shown (logo, description, download our app, log in button, etc.)
- When the user logs in, a feed must be shown with the user's data (e.g. his timeline, photos, etc.)

In both cases the corresponding URL **must be the same**, e.g `https://myapp.com` and not `https://myapp.com/feed` for the latter.

I need to know if my implementation is the correct way of doing it and more importantly if it has any **security issues**. If it is incorrect, an example would be very much appreciated.

My `routes` file:

```
# Home page
GET     /          controllers.Application.index()
```

My `Application.java`:

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import securesocial.core.Identity;
import securesocial.core.java.SecureSocial;
import views.html.feed;
import views.html.index;

public class Application extends Controller {

    @SecureSocial.UserAwareAction
    public static Result index() {
        Identity user = (Identity) ctx().args.get(SecureSocial.USER_KEY);
        if (user == null) {
            return ok(index.render());
        } else {
            return ok(feed.render(user));
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `UserAwareAction` is the way to go, then it's up to your action code and template to show/hide things as needed.